# Find m, n and p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $m, n$, and primes $p ≥ 5$ such that
$m(4m^2 + m + 12) = 3(p^n − 1)$

> I factorized L.H.S. and then used the fact that L.H.S. must be odd since R.H.S. is odd
>   Further as the factors are $(m^2+3)(4m+1)$ then $(m^2+3)$ must be odd since $(4m+1)$ is odd.
>   That means $m$ must be even. I then substituted $m=2k$. Equation became $(4k^2+3)(8k+1)=3p^n$.
>   Then I made two cases : Either $3$ divides $(4k^2+3)$ or $3$ divides $(8k+1)$. But then I couldn't go any further.

Comment: RHS is even! Is it a typo?

Comment: @rewritten:  the left side is even, as well.  what is the problem?

Comment: The OP says "used the fact that L.H.S. must be odd since R.H.S. is odd"

Comment: It is actually $m(4m^2+m+12)+3=3p^n$ which gives the factorization $(m^2+3)(4m+1)=3p^n$.

Comment: I find $m=12,p=7,n=4$  I bet that is the only solution because the exponents are large.

Comment: It would help to show the equation you want to solve.  You did $$m(4m^2+m+12)=3(p^n-1)\\(m^2+3)(4m+1)=3p^n$$  Now it is true that the right side is odd, so the left side must be as well, so $m=2k$, giving $$(4k^2+3)(8k+1)=3p^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ p\mid m^2\!+3,\, 4m\!+\!1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ m\equiv -\frac{1}4\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv m^2\!+3\equiv \frac{49}{16}\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid 49\,\Rightarrow\, p=7$

Answer (score 0):

$(m^2+3)(4^m+1)=3p^n$ and $m=2k$ as you wrote:

Case 1: $3|(4k^2+3)$ so $3|k$

Case 2: Since $k=0,1,2 \mod{3}$ in order for $8k+1=0\mod{3}$ we must have $k=1\mod{3}$

According to what you wrote, I think these can help you to continue.